# How to capture when dropdown is open on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to tell when the dropdown is open and also closed? onfocus and onblur doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div className="select-container">
  <select>
    {options.map((option) => (
      <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
     ))}
  </select>
</div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `useState` to keep track of the dropdown status.  It would look something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [isDropDownOpen, setDropDownOpen] = useState(false);

  let options = [
    {
      label: "money"
    }
  ];

  const handleSelect = () => {
    setDropDownOpen(!isDropDownOpen);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setDropDownOpen(!isDropDownOpen);
  };

  console.log(isDropDownOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <select onBlur={handleBlur} onClick={handleSelect}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tied it into the `handleSelect` function, which will probably do more than just keep track of whether or not the dropdown is open but either way, it works as a reference point for now.

EDIT:  Also, in case you click outside the dropdown, I used `onBlur`, which is controlled by `handleBlur` to change the boolean value because obviously, the dropdown will close.

Check the `console.log` on the this code sandbox to see how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-easley-0mf7o3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If I used the state to make a button appear when dropdown is open, how do I make sure clicking that button gets activated before the state changes to false. clicking the button has a blur effect on the dropdown that intern make the button disappear leaving the click on the button ineffective

Comment: I would have to see what you're trying to do.  Having a button with a list of dropdown options seems a little unique.  If you want to do something based on the selected value, that's conventional enough but if you're trying to leave the dropdown open while the button prompts something else, that's a little more indepth.